# Passing Arguments to super from the widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, super, lint

Im trying to pass arguments from my widget's state into a super class, but i cannot access the "widget." from the initialization list.
if i do pass it from the variables and accept an additional parameter in the state's ctor, i get the lint error:
`no_logic_in_create_state`

Here's my code:

```
class TransferPage extends View {
  final String screenId;
  TransferPage(this.screenId, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: no_logic_in_create_state
  State<TransferPage> createState() => TransferPageState(screenId);
}

class TransferPageState extends ViewState<TransferPage, TransferController> {
  final String screenId;

  TransferPageState(this.screenId)
      : super(TransferController(GetTransferDataUsecaseParams(screenId)));
```

I want to pass the id into the "super" ctor,
What's the best way to go about it?